# PHP code server changing visitors IP

Tags: php, xml, jobamatic

OK, I'm pulling jobs from the jobamatic api which is provided by simply hired. The problem that I'm having with the following code is that I'm able to echo the visitors IP correctly using $ip but for some reason the visitors ip is being replaced with my servers ip, I assume that it's happening just before the xml request but I can't figure it out.

I hope that I've given enough details but here's the code:

```
<?php
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$url = "http://api.simplyhired.com/a/jobs-api/xml-v2/l-Illinois/ws-100/?pshid=37990&    ssty=2&cflg=r&jbd=imax.jobamatic.com&clip=$ip";
 $xml = simplexml_load_file ($url);
 $file2 = file_get_contents('http://example.com/centerad.php');
 for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
 $jt = $xml->rs->r[$i]->jt;
 $cn = $xml->rs->r[$i]->cn;
 $loc = $xml->rs->r[$i]->loc;
 $src = $xml->rs->r[$i]->src;
 $loc = $xml->rs->r[$i]->loc;
 $e = $xml->rs->r[$i]->e;
 $tr = $xml->rs->r[$i]->tr;
 $link = $xml->rs->r[$i]->src['url'];
 $dp = $xml->rs->r[$i]->dp;
 $html .="<div><a rel='nofollow' href='$link' target='_blank' onMouseDown='xml_sclk(this);'>$jt</a><br/><span style='color:#008000'>$loc</span<br/>$e</div><hr />";
 }
 echo $html;
 echo $file2;
 for ($z = 5; $z < 11; $z++) {
 $jt2 = $xml->rs->r[$z]->jt;
 $cn2 = $xml->rs->r[$z]->cn;
 $loc2 = $xml->rs->r[$z]->loc;
 $src2 = $xml->rs->r[$z]->src;
 $loc2 = $xml->rs->r[$z]->loc;
 $e2 = $xml->rs->r[$z]->e;
 $tr2 = $xml->rs->r[$z]->tr;
 $link2 = $xml->rs->r[$z]->src['url'];
 $dp2 = $xml->rs->r[$z]->dp;
 $html2 .="<div><a rel='nofollow' href='$link' target='_blank'  onMouseDown='xml_sclk(this);'>$jt2</a><br/><span style='color:#008000'>$loc2</span<br/>$e2</div><hr />";
 }
 echo $html2;
 ?>
```

Comment: could `ssty=2&cflg=r&jbd=imax.jobamatic.com&clip=$ip` have anything to do with it?

Comment: the only reason REMOTE_ADDR would return the servers ip is if you are viewing  the page from the server, is your server a local server?

Comment: @ PatrickEvans I have a vps hosted elsewhere. REMOTE_ADDR does not give the servers ip but somewhere in the process it gets changed to the servers ip. I was told by the staff at simplyhired that it may be some sort of redirect that changes the ip before it reaches them.

Comment: @CiaranBaselmans the problem is that the $ip should attched the visitors ip there and it seems that it does just that but for some reason by the time the xml request is made my servers ip is placed there instead.

Answer (score 0):

The client IP might be replaced by your servers IP, when a proxy is running.

Client -> IP1 -> Server(Proxy) -> IP2 -> Server

Then you would get IP2, instead of IP1.

Passing the original IP is a configuration issue of the proxy.
You might check `var_dump($_SERVER);` for an possible client ip.

Check the following things:

```
$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]; // not the one you want
$ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]; // if behind proxy
$ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"]
```

Comment: REMOTE_ADDR is the only one of those options that will even allow the xml to be reterived. In other word when using the other two options, I get a blank page.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem, but failed. The code you posted works. (Except minimal PHP error notices: $html and $html2 are undefined.) One last thing: if you run this on CLI then try $ip = gethostbyname(gethostname()); . Else take a look at this: https://github.com/techmission/cv_simplyhired_feeds/blob/master/simplyhired/simplyhired-api.class.php#L269